# Equivalence relation $x \sim y$ if $x = \lambda y$ for a non-zero real number $\lambda$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations, projective-space, quotient-spaces

Let $X = \mathbb{R}^{n}\setminus \{0\}$, where $0$ is the origin in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

For $x, y \in X $ we define $x \sim y$ as follows:

> $x \sim y$ if there exists a nonzero real number $λ$ such that $x = λy$ ($λ$ may depend on the particular $x$ and $y$, it is not a fixed constant).

(a) Show that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on $X$.

(b) Show that any two equivalence classes $[x]$ and $[\tilde{x}]$, $x, \tilde{x} \in X $, are either
disjoint or they coincide.

(c) Describe the set $X/ ∼$ geometrically, i.e., what is the equivalence class $[x]$ if $x ∈ X$?

Comment: What have you tried? (a) and (b) are standard computations. For (c) think about the set off all the "lines" in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that pass through the origin, i.e. the one dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: You should ***really*** work on your titles.

Comment: @AsafKaragila True. On the other hand, as we all know, such titles are a pretty good indicator of the amount of personal input in the question, and as such, they **are** useful.

Comment: Chou sha bi que tm xin yan ba

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to proof the axioms of a equivalence relation:
[Axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation#Definition)

The following are just hints

(a) Reflexivity $\lambda = 1$, Symmetry use $\frac{1}{\lambda}$, Transitivity use the product of the factors which appear

(b) is just a consequence of the fact that $\sim$ is a equivalence relation. Transitivity is the key.

(c) $1$-dimensional subspace that contains $x$ (a line)